# Libroffice Calc - macro to iterate filter in 2 loops?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic, filterfunction

Hello everybody first of all I'm noob about macro programming in LibreOffice but have something outdated experience in programming and with MS Office macro Recorder as well.

Using LibreOffice Ubuntu Linux with Microsoft Windows 10.

I got a spreadsheet with that of columns that all have Filter activated.

One column is day of the week.
Another is name of of employee.

I want to create daily schedule printouts to PDF.

This for you want to iterator the day of week List created by the filter.
Inside every loop of the day Monday to Friday (I'm using set of strings to identify them with the number and shortcut like 1 equal Monday , 5 = Friday... zero =free planning)

In every day Loop  needs to iterate the item's in employees list.

... If possible I want to include one value as a placeholder in both lists active to create empty lines for last minute add-on.

Finally it should be printed landscape with width 1 page height whatever needs (I set a 99 manually so far) to PDF or printer.

Any ideas how to start?

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: Yes, Mike, this **can be** done in Calc too: you need at least two sheets - data for the report and a "template" of report (a sheet marked up for output as you described). The macro can select visible cells, loop through them, putting the data into a template and export it to PDF. But there are no complex calculations in your task, it's just a data transformation from one format to another, isn't it? So you have chosen the wrong instrument. Please look towards [**Base**](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLy7Kah3WzqrEerJ0VPNWVaR4CYHMr4wmV). There this task can be solved without macros

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.
I current try hard to get a team of IT noobs used to calc/Excel as an easy Instrument.

They only fail setting the filters before printing.
Usual we filter day and teacher to print a individuell list per day.

So the idea was to have a macro or Script to automate filtering and printing by Iteration of all teachers per day and have a print or PDF.

I d prefer to start it als a real DB but current just short in time the hope was to make IT easy (as No one seems to read the Illustrated howto...)



All in calc...

Comment: So my questions are
How to get all list Items per Filter in a colum
How to activate deactivate single Filter Items
How to iterate Item List
How to Start a printout
How to set Page settings

Comment: This is a very broad topic. I can provide links to answers to each of the questions asked. For example, [iterate over the filtered data](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=106859&p=519760#p519760) or [print specific range](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-print-automatic-in-a-macro/5449/2?u=johnsun), but this will not be a complete solution to your problem. This resource does not allow long discussions, and the solution to your problem requires many refinements (for example, an approximate data sample and output template).